# Join List<> with List of <List<> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

There are `List<Products>` which has `List<ProductOffers>` like below:

```
class Products
{
   public List<ProductOffers> ProductOffers { get; set; }
}

class ProductOffers
{
    public string ProductOfferId { get; set; }
    public string ProductSubscription {get;set;}
}
```

There is another `List<Offers>` which also has `offerId`.

```
class Offers
{
public string offerId {get;set;}
public string subscription{get;set;}
}
```

I want to join both list depend on the `products.ProductOffers.ProductOfferId = offers.OfferId.`Then I have to assign the matching subscription to ProductSubscription. How can I achieve this using LINQ/lambda expression?

Comment: finally what output you want, please make it clear

Comment: Join? Do you mean SQL-like join? Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: @freedomn-m - The  Entity Framework is also using LINQ, so there is no need of being so snarky. Many people don't know the difference, and it's important to clarify whether we're working with `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`. Here, it does *look like* EF naming conventions, but the OP didn't mention it.

Comment: use virtual keyword to include the reference in the classes and then use `.Include` to get the data

Comment: @KFC, Where do you want to assign the result to? To which property?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    List<products> Prod=//assigned list of product.
    List<Offers> Offer=//assigned list of offer.

     List<Offers> filteredOffer=(from O in Offer
                         ((from sa in Prod where (sa.ProductOffers.Where(d => d.ProductOfferId == O.OfferId).Select(d=>d.ProductOfferId).Count()>0) select sa).Count()>0).toList();
```

now you can use this filtered `Offers` list  for your further use

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a solution below. In this, I have added a new method called `SetSubscription` in your `ProductOffers` class. Please check if this helps or not.

```
class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var products = new List<Products>();

        var offers = new List<Offers>();

        products.All(t => t.ProductOffers.All(s => s.SetSubscription(offers.First(r => r.OfferId == s.ProductOfferId))));
    }
}



public class Products
{
    public List<ProductOffers> ProductOffers { get; set; }
}

public class ProductOffers
{
    public string ProductOfferId { get; set; }
    public string ProductSubscription { get; set; }
    public bool SetSubscription(Offers offerDets)
    {
        if (offerDets != null)
        {
            this.ProductSubscription = offerDets.subscription;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Offers
{
    public string OfferId { get; set; }
    public string subscription { get; set; }
}
```